# Excel: left of a reference

Tags: excel, reference

The cell C4 points to cell E4 (but in my real workbook E4 is another sheet). I want cell C5 to point to the right of whatever cell C4 points to. So I only have to change C4 pointer to make C5 change as well - always to the cell to the right of whatever C4 points to. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: On the screenshot C4 points to cell E4, not E5?

Comment: @pnuts don't think you understood my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offset() and Indirect() work perfectly together like this, if you add an option to read the formula from a VBA custom function:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CellFormula(C4));0;1)
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CellFormula(Rng As Range) As String

    CellFormula = Right(Rng.Formula, Len(Rng.Formula) - 1)

End Function
```

You do not need the custom function, if you are using Excel 2013. Then `FormulaText` does exactly the same. Just make sure to eliminate the equal (=) sign on the left from `FormulaText`, if you are using it.

Comment: FormulaText also returns the "=". you need to be something like: `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(C4);2);TRUE);0;1)`

Comment: @Axel - if you want to make it robust, the `Right(Formula,2)` should include the length of the formula as in the custom formula. Otherwise it would not work for `AA12` for example. But in general, you are right about `FormulaText`.

Comment: I would ideally like to not use vba. @Axel: I cant find formulatext function in my excel...

Comment: @Erosennin - you are probably not using Excel 2013, but an older version. That's why you do not have it.

Comment: @Vityata: True, I'm using 2010 :s

Answer (score 1):

if VBA is an Option

```
Range("c5").Value = Range("c4").Precedents.Offset(0, 1)
```